# MULTIBIT: How to restore wallet with following information?

Tags: wallet, multibit, wallet-recovery

I am a noob to this whole BTC thing, so please bear with me.

I reformatted my computer and lost everything on it.
I decided I want to restore my multibit wallet but I only have the following info:

- Secret words
- Old password

I do not have a backup of the wallet file or whatever it is called.

My question is, how do I reopen this wallet with that information? It has a lot of BTCs it in and I really want to salvage it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

The MultiBit HD wallet can be restored with just the seed words. Click "Restore" on the unlock screen and follow the instructions.

Answer (score -2):

I would start with a data recovery service. As far as I know the password will only unlock the backup file, it's like having the key to a lockbox but not the lockbox!

A data recovery service might be able to retrieve the backup file (maybe!)